# How to differentiate whether machine is online on network or on internet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, networking, wifi, lan

We would like to differentiate if machines are online on a network over LAN/WiFi or using internet connectivity, using `AngularJS/JavaScript`.

Comment: What's the difference between LAN/WiFI and "internet connectivity"? In any case, it's very unlikely that the browser provides this information.

Comment: If machines are connected through LAN/WIFI they might not necessarily will be connected to internet for browsing.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way from the server point of view is to ping to an internal machine in the same LAN and to ping to some external machine outside your LAN